# How to compare 2 arrays in 2 columns of a picker view and display the result in single text field

Tags: ios

I mean to say is if I have 2 arrays like

> Array1 a, b, c, d, e
>
> Array2 c,d,b,a,e

Now if I select `a` in `Array1` and `b` in `Array2` it must show as **`ab`** in the textbox

And if I take both same alphabet `aa` in both arrays so I must display a single **`a`** Kindly help me with the code as I am new to iOS learning

Comment: store both the values in temporary variable and compare using "isEqualToString" and display the output.

Comment: Can u pls write the xcode with proper syntax and upload so that I can test and learn it I am new to this field pls help me that would be gr

Comment: if ([pickerValueA isEqualToString pickerValueB]) then textField.text = pickerValueA ELSE textField.text = [pickerValueA stringByAppendingString pickerValueB]

Comment: @chinmay can you use the Larcerax code.. Or still do you need code snippet?

Comment: I need the Complete code bro pls

Comment: i'll post real code, one sec

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, you'll have to do the rest:

```
#import "NSHGingerViewController.h"

@interface NSHGingerViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation NSHGingerViewController
{
    NSString * b;
    NSString * c;
    UITextField * this;
    NSArray * array1;
    NSArray * array2;
    NSArray * array3;
    NSArray * array4;
    UIPickerView * picker1;
    UIPickerView * picker2;
}

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [picker1 setTag:345];
    [picker2 setTag:243];
    [picker1 setDataSource:self];
    [picker2 setDataSource:self];
    [picker1 setDelegate:self];
    [picker2 setDelegate:self];
    array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"China",@"USA",@"UK",@"SL",nil];
    array3=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];
    array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"China",@"USA",@"UK",@"SL",@"india",nil];
    array4=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView.tag == 345) {
        return [array1 count];
    } else {
        return [array2 count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView.tag == 345) {
        return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView.tag == 345) {
        b = [array1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    } else {
        c = [array2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    }
    if ([b isEqualToString:c]) {
        this.text = b;
    } else {
        this.text = [b stringByAppendingString:c];
    }
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel* pickerLabel = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!pickerLabel) {
        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        pickerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        pickerLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
    }
    if(pickerView.tag == 345) {
        [pickerLabel setText:[array3 objectAtIndex:row]];
    } else {
        [pickerLabel setText:[array4 objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    return pickerLabel;
}

@end
```

Comment: Gys pls perform the Complete operation right from Dec 2 arrays as I mentioned

Comment: @hello that's cool bro but can u give the Complete coding bro right from the start of making a dynamic picker view and dragging a text from story board

Comment: Friends I am on a mac machine rit now so if u send the Complete code I can run it immediately... I that would be really helpful and there would be many more queries to come

Comment: I would, Chinmay, but PICKER VIEWS are really really terrible to make, especially with a storyboard, they require delegation and more, so, I've gotta bow out for this one

Comment: pls bro I need ur help take ur time an hour is enough for u to develop rit make it anyway as u do but pls provide me the Complete code that would be really helpful

Comment: There is not only me waiting for ur code but my entire batch is depending on me and I am depending on u

Comment: Thanx bro that's a great help

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *ValueA = [arrayA objectAtIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>];
NSString *ValueB = [arrayB objectAtIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>];



if ([ValueA isEqualToString ValueB]) {
    textField.text = ValueB
} else {
    textField.text = [pickerValueA stringByAppendingString pickerValueB]

}
```

Comment: Bro what should be written in the place of nsuiinteger... I am confused here

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView *pickerView;
    int a;
}


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    a=0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"China",@"USA",@"UK",@"SL",nil];
    array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"China",@"USA",@"UK",@"SL",@"india",nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //NSLog(@"Working");
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,300, 300)];
    pickerView.dataSource=self;
    pickerView.delegate=self;
    //pickerView.tag=1;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        switch(a)
        {
            case 1:
                return [array1 count];
                break;
            case 2:
                return [array2 count];
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default:
            return @"nothing";
    }

}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            b = [array1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            break;
        case 2:
            c = [array2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
## Heading ##
```

Comment: this is my code pla make changes and make a proper code... that would do a great help

Comment: @Larcerax yeah bro but it's not showing my picker pls see that and also add up ur statement so that when 2 arrays are selected they get compared and displayed as one

Comment: i don't use storyboards, so I wouldnt' be able to help you there

Comment: No problem for the story board u do it your way and try it I need only the result bro thanx alot I know my code sucks there would be a lot of mistakes